# Single word clues to decipher codewords

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, cipher

Two pieces of information are known about a code language:

1. One of the Greek letters is **Pea**23
2. The past tense of 13**Tea** is 11**Tea**

---

Each codeword in the table is associated with a single word clue.

***Decipher all codewords***

| Codeword | Clue |
| --- | --- |
| **Pea**13 + **Tea**13 | Food |
| 1**Tea**4 + 1**Tea**3 | Animal |
| 1**Tea**5 + **Pea**13 | Buddhism |
| **Tea**22 + **Tea**22 | Sleep |
| **Tea**24 + **Tea**23 | Thug |
| **Tea**23 + **Tea**33 | Organ |
| **Tea**23 + **Tea**23 + **Pea**13 | Tennis |

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code:

> **Tea** encodes T. **Pea** encodes P. In a group of two digits from 1 to 5, one of them encodes one of the vowels A, E, I, O or U according to its value, the other encodes the letter S. So:
>
>  One of the Greek letters is **PSI**
>  The past tense of **SIT** is **SAT**

The codewords:

> (P)13 + (T)13: **PASTAS**, Italian food
>  1(T)4 + 1(T)3: **STOATS**, animals
>  1(T)5 + (P)13: [**STUPAS**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stupa), a place of meditation in Buddhism
>  (T)22 + (T)22: **TSETSE**, a fly that can cause sleeping sickness
>  (T)24 + (T)23: [**TSOTSI**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsotsi), a film about a street thug
>  (T)23 + (T)33: **TESTIS**, a male reproduction organ
>  (T)23 + (T)23 + (P)13: Stefanos [**TSITSIPAS**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefanos_Tsitsipas), a tennis player